Mainframe Z/os - JCL: include line breaks after each character string read
I need to do a line break whenever I find the string 'AAA' in each record read. So I successfully executed the command OUTREC FINDREP=(INOUT=(C'AAA',X'0A') but when I open the output file, I don't find newlines, I just find a hexadecimal replacement of AAA by 0A.
Doesn't the X'0A' really represent a line break if we mention it like that in the JCL directly?

X'0A' is a linefeed for PC and not on mainframes.  So if you FTP the file then you will see the line break. However there are ways to split the record when AAA is found. Please post a sample of input data and desired output along with LRECL, REFCM of the data.

Please think about what a sequential data set is, and how that maps to line breaks.  Are you supposed to be adding line breaks, or creating a new record?

Hello,
Thank you for your response
Indeed it is / instead of x'0A'.
The file is VB and size 10000.
So, my input data is as follows:
AAAabc
DeAAAfghi
jklmnAAAopq
rstuvwxAAAyz
I want to have an Output like this:
AAA
abcde
AAA
fghijklmn
AAA
opqrstuvwx
AAA
yz

As zos uses an EBCDIC based character set you need to change AAA to the Line Feed char x'25' or the Carriage Return New Line Combo x'0D' x'15' if you target is windows.
